# Add border to the form

Tags: css

I wrote the following code to form creation,I have add some style to my form.Now 
I want to add border like this to my form.I tride,But unable to add it.
Can anyone help me to do this?

[image]

```css
.details {
  background-color: #eb4e24;
  height: 800px;
}
input[type=text],
#uexperience,
#equalification,
#roles {
  width: 86%;
  padding: 7px 7px;
  border: #c1c1c1 solid 1px;
  height: 40px;
  background: none;
  /*border-radius: 5px;*/
}
select {
  width: 28%;
  height: 37px;
  padding: 0 1em;
  background: none;
  border: #c1c1c1 solid 1px;
}
.border {
  border: #dbdbdb solid 1px;
}
table td {
  padding: 10px;
}
input[type=file] {
  border: #c1c1c1 solid 1px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 8px 7px;
  width: 86%;
}
label {
  color: red;
}
#captcha {
  width: 77%;
}
.fa {
  font-size: 2em !important;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
form {
  margin-top: 15%;
  /*border: 1px solid;*/
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <form>
          <table width="100%">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  First Name
                  <label>*</label>
                  <br>
                  <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" class="">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  Email Address
                  <label>*</label>
                  <br>
                  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  Job position
                  <label>*</label>
                  <br>
                  <input type="text" name="position" id="position" class="">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  Current Employer
                  <label>*</label>
                  <br>
                  <input type="text" name="currentemp" id="currentemp" class="">
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 details">
        <form>
          <table width="100%">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  Last Name
                  <label>*</label>
                  <br>
                  <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" class="">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  Mobile No.
                  <label>*</label>
                  <br>

                  <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  Experience
                  <label>*</label>
                  <br>
                  <select id="uexperience" class="decorated">
                    <option id="selectHeader">--------- Select Experience --------------</option>
                    <option value="1-2 YEAR">1-2 Years</option>
                    <option value="1-3 YEAR">1-3 Years</option>
                    <option value="2-4 YEAR">2-4 Years</option>
                    <option value="4-6 YEAR">4-6 Years</option>
                    <option value="6-10 YEAR">6-10 Years</option>
                    <option value=">10 YEAR">&gt; 10 Years</option>
                  </select>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  Enter code Here
                  <label>*</label>
                  <br>
                  <input type="text" name="captcha" id="captcha"><i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </td>
              </tr>

            </tbody>
          </table>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Complete code here https://jsfiddle.net/qxoos44h/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a border in two colors you can use this little trick:

```css
body {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #FFF 50%, #000 50%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #FFF 50%, #000 50%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #FFF 50%, #000 50%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #FFF 50%, #000 50%);
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

form {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  border-left: 10px solid #000;
  border-right: 10px solid #FFF;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #000 50%, #FFF 50%), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #000 50%, #FFF 50%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #000 50%, #FFF 50%), -moz-linear-gradient(left, #000 50%, #FFF 50%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #000 50%, #FFF 50%), -o-linear-gradient(left, #000 50%, #FFF 50%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #000 50%, #FFF 50%), linear-gradient(to right, #000 50%, #FFF 50%);
  background-position: 0 0, 0 100% ;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 10px;
}
```

```html
<form></form>
```

### How does this work?

The borders to the right and left are real borders while the border at the top and bottom are really just an background image.

To make the "color-split" effect we are going to use a background-image as the top and bottom borders. We do that by making two identical gradients.

**The first color** starts from `0%` and ends on `50%`.

**The second color** starts from `50%` and ends on `100%`

We then use `background-position` to place the first gradient at the top, and the second at the bottom of the `form`.

To make our "fake borders" the same thickness as our "real borders" we're using `background-size` to change the width and height, of the image.

Finally we are also setting the background to `no-repeat`. Else the gradient would fill the entire form and thereby destroy the border illusion.

---

But in your case there also is another simple way.

Since you use columns next to each other, you can just apply the borders to those, and have them in different colors, and hide the `left-border` on the right column, and the `right-border` at the left column. Like this:

```
.col-lg-6 {
  height: 800px;
  border: 10px solid #eb4e24;
  border-right: 0;
}

.col-lg-6.details {
  border: 10px solid #FFF;
  border-left: 0;
}
```

To gain the best effect, you should set the same height to both of the columns, and apply the "split-color" background to the container of the columns, with a padding. Else the white border at the right column, would blend with the background.

---

### UPDATE - Centered Headline

If you want to add a headline on the top border, so it looks like the text is overlaying you can do it like this:

```
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #FFF 50%, #eb4e24 50%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #FFF 50%, #eb4e24 50%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #FFF 50%, #eb4e24 50%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #FFF 50%, #eb4e24 50%);
  font-size: 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%,0,0);
  padding: 0 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 10;
}

h1 span {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #eb4e24 50%, #FFF 50%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #eb4e24 50%, #FFF 50%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #eb4e24 50%, #FFF 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #eb4e24 50%, #FFF 50%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}
```

The `h1` centers the headline and have a background gradient, matching the one at the `.container` so it looks like, that a part has been cut out.

The `span` also uses a gradient as background, but reversed to its parent. Then uses `background-clip: text` and `color: transparent` to put the gradient over the text.

See full code in Fiddle below:

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qxoos44h/8/)

Hope this could help you.

Comment: Thank you so much.Is it possible to add headline between border?

Answer (score 0):

Set form content into fieldset (just after the form and before the /form), set Title into the fieldset, at the first line, and set a border (2px solid #000, for example) on the fieldset.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the approatch using 2 forms is easyer because that way you dont have to worry about the font color beeing readable on 2 backgrounds.
But this altough results in having to worry about them both beeing the same hight.

Then you can use a border on the container arround each of the forms and removed the padding betwen them

```
.left{
padding-right: 0;
}
.left form{
border-style: solid;
border-right-style: none;
height: 620px;

}

.right{
padding-left: 0;
background-color: #eb4e24;
}

.right form{
border-style: solid;
border-left-style: none;
border-color: white;
height: 620px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qxoos44h/1/